# How to sum RGBA colors

Tags: c++, graphics, rgb, rgba

I'm searching a way to sum two [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) colors. Here's what I do :

```
RGBA c1, c2
RGB c3 = rgba_to_rgb(c1)
RGB c4 = rgba_to_rgb(c2)

RGB r = c3 + c4

RGBA r1 = rgb_to_rgba(r) // I don't know how to implement this function
```

How can I sum c1 and c2 without converting them to RGB. In my program I have to sum four RGBA colors. I have this instruction :

```
Color r = 1.f/4 * (c1+c2+c3+c4)
```

I have to implement the + operator for RGBA colors.

**Edit:**

For RGB color when sum two colors I do this :

```
RGB r;
r.red = c1.red + c2.red
r.green = c1.green + c2.green
r.blue = c1.blue + c2.blue
```

I don't know what to do for RGBA color. My first idea is to convert the two colors to RGB then do the sum (because I know how to do it for RGB colors) then convert back to RGBA. The second solution is to find out how to directly the addition with RGBA colors.

Comment: That's what I don't how to do. I will edit my question.

Comment: RGBA is RGB with alpha channel.

Comment: I just know that it doesn't work like that. I suppose that there's a formula for doing the addition but I don't know it.

Comment: You may look at [Alpha_compositing](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) to see how to blend colour.